# Get bluetooth device connection strength

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, bluetooth, swift

I'm doing a side project app that uses wearable devices like fitbit, jawbone and fuelband to track some physical activities and exercises.

I want to use the Bluetooth connection/signal strength to know the position of the device relative to my phone.

What is the best way to get this information?

Comment: Sorry, I was using the mobile site and wasn't able to find any duplicate.

Comment: thats why i have added the answer below . mark my answer if it helped you.